# Ajax error when running jQuery getJSON

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, json, jsp

I'm running this getJSON async call in jQuery to get the data back into and then out of my Java code.  For whatever reason I continually get the error:

```
"Ajax Error: Error invoking generateSearchQuery([object Object])"
```

I've debugged both the jQuery and the Java code.  The Java code receives the JSON data, processes it, and writes it back without a problem.  The jQuery code kicks the error when it gets into the internal getJson method and tries `if(json.successful)`.

The response is: `{"error":{"message":"","title":"Error Generating Search Query"},"data":[Ljava.lang.String;@1e40c9f,"successful":"successful"}`

I've been working on this async call for a few days now, but still can't get it working.  Any ideas?

jQuery function:

```
generate : function(){

    getJson(
        Search.guid,
        "generateSearchQuery",
        {
            "data": [
                "val0",
                "val1",
                "val2",
                "val3",
                "val4"
            ]
        }, function(json) {
            Search.data = $.parseJSON(json.data);

            $.each(Search.data, function(k, v){
                $('#searchQuery').append(v + "\n");
            });
        });
},
```

Java function:

```
    @AsyncService(name = "generateSearchQuery", permission = "")
    public void generateSearchQuery(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) {
        res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        JSONResult result = new JSONResult("Error Generating Search Query");

        String[] arr = req.getParameterValues("data[]");

        for(int i = 0; i< arr.length; i++){
            arr[i] = "success"+i+"!";
        }

        result.put("data", arr);

        try {
            res.getWriter().print(result);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // whatever
        }
    }
}
```

getJson:

```
function getJson(guid, service, parms, callback) {
    beginWork();
    $
            .ajax( {
                url : document.URL,
                type : 'GET',
                data : parms,
                cache : 'false',
                dataType : 'json',
                headers : {
                    'framework-guid' : guid,
                    'async-service' : service
                },
                success : function(json) {
                    endWork();
                    if (json.successful) {
                        callback(json);
                    } else {
                        error(json.error && json.error.title ? json.error.title
                                : 'No Title Provided', json.error
                                && json.error.message ? json.error.message
                                : 'No message provided for service ' + service);
                    }
                },
                error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    endWork();
                    error('Ajax Error', 'Error invoking ' + service + '('
                            + parms + ')');
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not a debugging service](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135066/173320) You should try debug the code, locate where is the problem then, ask a concrete question.

Comment: Could it possibly be because you have `getJSON` instead of `$.getJSON`?

Comment: What is `getJson`?  Is that a wrapper for `$.getJSON`?  [`$.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) only takes 3 parameters, and it also parses the JSON for you (no need for `$.parseJSON`).

Comment: @gdoron, I have been debugging it.  Everything seems to work fine until it gets into jQuery's getJSON method where it checks: `if (json.successful) {` then kicks the error, then runs my Java code but doesn't pass the result back to the jQuery side.

Comment: What does the response look like. Put that on the page. Use a tool like Fiddler to get the response.

Comment: Ok, so I changed it to $.getJSON and I get `"Ajax Error: error"`.  I debugged it and it's going to a completely different method, so I think that getJson might be something that was written by someone else.  I posted it to the OP.

Comment: Resonse: `{"error":{"message":"","title":"Error Generating Search Query"},"data":[Ljava.lang.String;@1e40c9f,"successful":"successful"}`

Comment: @PseudoPsyche the response doesn't seam to be valid!

Comment: I checked it, you have an invalid label there **Ljava.lang.String;@1e40c9f**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the content of the response from server wasn't json format. Because you specify the type of response of $.ajax as json, so you need to convert object result to json. You can use google gson http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/, and do something like the followings.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
res.getWriter().print(gson.toJson(result));
```

And in getJson, you should make the following changes.

```
//before
Search.data = $.parseJSON(json.data);
//after
Search.data = json.data;
```

Comment: This worked the first time, but the second time I tried running it the console out put `json is null` at `if(json.successful)`

Comment: Ah, nevermind!  I restarted my JBoss server and it all works fine!  Thanks!  This was also pretty convenient since I'm already using Gson elsewhere in this app, so the libraries were already there.

Comment: I can't find out a reason explain it. But it is clearly you should return a string with json format on the server if you use such javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The response doesn't seam to be valid!

I checked it, you have an invalid label there **Ljava.lang.String;@1e40c9f**, the error i get when parsing your code is:

```
SyntaxError: invalid label
```